# Adding meta tag keywords - the same or different on all pages?

Tags: seo, search-engines, meta-tags

I have 10 page php website. I want to add keywords to webpages.

The website is related to hotel and having different-2 page like booking, rooms, places to visit etc.

Question: Do we need to add same meta tag with all keyword for each webpage or should I create one meta tag page and include them in all pages?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use separate meta tags for each page of your site and the content of these tags should reflect the page content rather than the site theme.

For the record you are only going to get so far with Meta tags.

By far the most important thing to consider is the text within your title tag.

The Meta description tag can be useful and will be used by Google et al to create a search snippet (though it won't always be used and Google will grab bits of content relevant to the user's search query).

The Meta keywords tag is more or less useless. It won't do any harm to include it but don't expect it to have any effect at all.

Remember: Search engines index PAGES and not SITES. Make the content, title, meta description, any text linking TO the page and any ad campaigns pointing at the page all tie in together using your targeted key words and phrases.

The single most important thing is your page content. Make it "good", and don't try to build a site for a search engine - instead, build it for people. *That* is how to get good search visibility.

Comment: I concur with what @foamcow says.  Make sure that the keyword/phrase that page is about is well represented in your headings, links and a little bit spread about in your body copy, but really, Google rewards relevant CONTENT, not jazzed up meta tags.  To reiterate what he just told you:  Write for your users, NOT for Google.

Comment: thanks i like both of your idea.. now its clear to me ....

Answer (score 0):

Every one want to see their website on top for this your website should be user friendly as well as it should be search engine friendly too and every one know unique and fresh contech and meta tags help to search engine so if you want that your page of website on any keyword that you want on top then it is necessary to have separate meta tags of each pages.